# Java For() Loop Wrong Initial Value, Wrong Final Stopping Point

Tags: java, for-loop, local-variables

I ran into a problem with two for() loops in my code:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int numLayers;
    private int[] sizes;
    private Matrix[] biases;
    private Matrix[] weights;

    public Foo(int... sizes)
    {
        this.numLayers = sizes.length;
        this.sizes = sizes;
        this.weights = new Matrix[sizes.length - 1];
        this.biases = new Matrix[sizes.length - 1];
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        for(int layerNumber = 1; layerNumber < sizes.length; layerNumber++)
        {
            this.biases[layerNumber - 1] = new Matrix(sizes[layerNumber], 1);
            for(int i = 0; i < biases[layerNumber - 1].getHeight(); i++)
            {
                biases[layerNumber - 1].set(i, 0, randomNum.nextGaussian());
            }
        }
        for(int layerNumber = 0; layerNumber < sizes.length - 1; layerNumber++)
        {
            this.weights[layerNumber] = new Matrix(sizes[layerNumber + 1], sizes[layerNumber]);
            for(int i = 0; i < weights[layerNumber].getHeight(); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < weights[layerNumber].getWidth(); j++)
                    weights[layerNumber].set(i, j, randomNum.nextGaussian());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which ended up giving me a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` when I tried `Foo obj = new Foo(1, 2, 1);` in a tester class

So I went into my debugger and found that on the very first round of the first loop, `for(int layerNumber = 1; layerNumber < sizes.length; layerNumber++)`, the variable `layerNumber = 0`, not 1 as I intended it. Furthermore, on the first round of the second loop, `layerNumber = 1`, when it should be equal to 0 as I specify. Finally, sizes.length, the number of input ints into the constructor, is clearly 3 in this example (1, 2, 1), so if you have a for loop that cycles until layerNumber < sizes.length - 1, the loop should not execute when `layerNumber = 2` in my example. But it does. It only skips over the loop only when `layerNumber = 3`, which causes the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` error. The variable `layerNumber` is unique to each loop and local- it is not altered elsewhere. So what is the problem? It must be something simple which I have overlooked, but the problem seems so  perplexing I'm inclined to think it is a bug.

Comment: Calling your class `Object` is very likely to confuse a lot of people and may cause you severe headaches later, because all classes, including your `Object` class, derives from the `java.lang.Object` class, and having an `Object` class subclass `Object` is just plain confusing and error-prone.

Comment: You're correct. Thank you. It is now called Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(int layerNumber = 1; layerNumber < sizes.length; layerNumber++)
```

`layerNumber` reaches as high as `sizes.length - 1`.

at which point `biases[layerNumber]` is out of bounds, since the length of `biases` is `sizes.length - 1`, so its max index is `sizes.length - 2`.

Perhaps you intended the range of that loop to be the same as the range of the second loop :

```
for(int layerNumber = 1; layerNumber < sizes.length - 1; layerNumber++)
```

Comment: You're right, but even if I fix that (with  biases[layerNumber - 1].set(i, 0, randomNum.nextGaussian()); instead of biases[layerNumber]--that is what I intended) it still comes up with the same exception. In fact it says the exception is on line 43, the fourth to last bracket in the program, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @abeta201 If you get the exception on a line that is just an end-brace (`}`), then you are not running the code you are looking at. Remember to re-compile your code.

Comment: @Andreas That must be exactly what is going on. Eclipse won't recompile my code automatically. Any idea on how to force it to recompile code? I might have to just reinstall the thing- I was trying to update it to Mars just a little while ago. I guess it didn't work so well.

Comment: Going to Project -> Build Automatically seemed to fix the problem. Now Eclipse is finally recompiling my code again.